# Group_by string vector and add sequential code

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to add a sequential code to the duplicates values by grouping them.
It is transforming to a prefix and a unique ID for each.

```
*IDtest         Desired_ ID*
2021-11-0515    2021-11-0515-1
2021-11-0573    2021-11-0573-1
2021-11-0528    2021-11-0528-1
2021-11-055     2021-11-055-1
2021-11-0552    2021-11-0552-1
2021-11-0562    2021-11-0562-1
2021-11-0515    2021-11-0515-2
2021-11-0515    2021-11-0515-3
2021-11-0528    2021-11-0528-2
2021-11-0528    2021-11-0528-3
```

I tried:

```
test %>%
group_by(IDtest) %>%
paste(IDtest,"-", seq_along(IDtest) - 1)
```

I can only get a long array with all the data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
data.frame(IDtest) %>%
  group_by(IDtest) %>%
  mutate(IDtest_new = paste0(IDtest,"-", seq(1, length(IDtest))))
# A tibble: 10 x 2
# Groups:   IDtest [6]
   IDtest         IDtest_new    
   <chr>          <chr>         
 1 "2021-11-0515" 2021-11-0515-1
 2 "2021-11-0573" 2021-11-0573-1
 3 "2021-11-0528" 2021-11-0528-1
 4 "2021-11-055"  2021-11-055-1
 5 "2021-11-0552" 2021-11-0552-1
 6 "2021-11-0562" 2021-11-0562-1
 7 "2021-11-0515" 2021-11-0515-2
 8 "2021-11-0515" 2021-11-0515-3
 9 "2021-11-0528" 2021-11-0528-2
10 "2021-11-0528" 2021-11-0528-3
```

Data:

```
IDtest  <- 
c("2021-11-0515",  
"2021-11-0573",  
"2021-11-0528",  
"2021-11-055",
"2021-11-0552",  
"2021-11-0562",  
"2021-11-0515",  
"2021-11-0515",  
"2021-11-0528",  
"2021-11-0528")
```

Comment: Thats perfect. Thank you so much Chris.